# Obj-C - Dismissing all pushed view controllers causes crash?

Tags: ios, objective-c

When my user taps a button, I want to return to the first view controller in my push stack. I've logged the stack, and the following is returned:

```
[4352:924095] HERE IT IS (
    "<MapViewController: 0x10c014800>",
    "<MUAQuestionViewController: 0x10674b4f0>",
    "<MUAQuestionViewController: 0x10953e730>",
    "<MUAQuestionViewController: 0x10674e4b0>",
    "<MUAQuestionViewController: 0x1067502f0>",
    "<MUAQuestionViewController: 0x10949e5e0>",
    "<MUAQuestionViewController: 0x109549b90>"
)
```

When my user taps my "Close" button, I simply want them to be returned to MapViewController. That being said, when my user taps Close, the following crash occurs:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSDictionary
>   initWithObjects:forKeys:]: count of objects (0) differs from count of
>   keys (1)'

**Here's my code:**

```
- (IBAction)closeFinal:(id)sender {

    NSArray *array = [self.navigationController viewControllers];

    NSLog(@"HERE IT IS %@", array);

    [self.navigationController popToViewController:[array objectAtIndex:1] animated:YES];

    }
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: If `mapViewController` is first, it is `objectAtIndex:0`, not `objectAtIndex:1`.

Comment: @matt I tried that as well, still crash :/

Comment: No doubt, but showing code that doesn't do what you want is silly. The truth is that you should not be retaining `[self.navigationController viewControllers]` at all, because it is volatile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't retain the navigation controller's `viewControllers`; it is volatile (i.e. it will mutate behind your back). Just fetch out the view controller that you want. Here's a safe version:

```
UINavigationController* nav = self.navigationController;
if (nil != nav && nav.viewControllers.count > 0) {
    UIViewController* vc = [nav.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0];
    [nav popToViewController:vc animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: Tried this and I still get the same crash error. :/ Which seems strange because logging array clearly shows indexes exist?

Comment: Then something else is going on, in code you have not shown us. I ran this code and it works fine.

Comment: I even log vc, and it displays <MapViewController: 0x15d811000> as it should. Super bizarre :/

Comment: @matt popToRootViewControllerAnimated isn't safer than objectAtIndex?

Comment: @Brittany I guess you have something wrong in MapViewController viewWillAppear

Comment: @RajeshKumarR Oh no, I regard your answer as better. I simply wanted to show how to do safely what he was doing.

Answer (score 0):

You should use [popToRootViewControllerAnimated:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621855-poptorootviewcontrolleranimated) method to close all pushed view controllers

> Pops all the view controllers on the stack except the root view
>   controller and updates the display.

```
[self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```